# Jquery Dynamic Radio button show hide

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Essentially what is going on is that I'm using a database to create radio buttons and text fields.  Depending on which radio button is selected a different text field is shown.  That's the easy part.  The hard part is that all the names, classes, etc. are dynamic.  I've managed to get the script to work correctly with one exception.  It needs to cycle through and if something is selected leave it open.  Right now it is set up to close everything once you select a different radio button.  It only leaves the currently selected item open.  That is fine except it is closing the Checkbox as well.

How do I make it cycle through and leave the checked boxes' textfields visible?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


 var vals = $('clickme').val();

        $(".clickme").click(function(){
     var rels = '.'+$(this).attr('rel');
    if ($('input[rel='+rels+']:checked').val() == vals ) {
   $('.hideable,rel').css("display","none");
   $(rels).slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
     } else {
     $(rels).slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
     }
     $('.clickme input').each(function(){
       if(this.checked == true){
     var relreset = '.'+$(this).attr('rel');
     $(relreset).slideDown('fast');
    }
     });
  });
  var rels = '.'+$('clickme').attr('rel');
        var showTop = $.cookie('showTop');
});
```

The easy solution would be to loop through and create a separate function for each field but I'm trying to create something dynamic.  Something that we can use on many pages using the same principle.  The line $('.clickme input') is where I have attempted to remedy the problem.

I'd appreciate some help.  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using your .each() for showing the hidden/stopping, you could use you each for hiding. So you would do $('.clickme input').each(function(){
       if(this.checked != true){  or == false, if it is false, hide it, otherwise do nothing. also, this would be instead of hiding it before this.

Comment: of, alternatively, if you like a more CF solution, use <cfdiv> that binds to <cfinput type="radio">, and returns a HTML segment with correct textfield(s) from ColdFusion.

Comment: Henry,
   That's how we are currently doing things but the problem is that we have multiple sites running from the same root folder and we want to create a centralized function so that we can update them all from one place without having to have the full code on each page.  But yes, that is a good CF solution.
MoDFox,
   Thanks, I didn't really understand the .each() tag very well.  Still learning how jquery works for the most part.

Comment: ModFox, that worked well.  Thanks.  There is still a display issue there but I'm pretty sure that's more to do with the decision they made to use tables instead of divs (sigh).  Thanks for the good information though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who may use a similar feature, here is what I used.  It is such because having the hidden field marked as hidden in css beforehand causes issues.  So I assign the hidden when the page is loaded to avoid this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hideable').css('display','none');
    $('.clickme').each(function(){
                var relreset = '.'+$(this).attr('rel');
                if(this.checked == true){       
                    $(relreset).fadeIn('fast');
                }else if(this.selected == true){
                    $(relset).fadeIn('fast');
                }else{
                    $(relreset).fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });

    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        $('.clickme').each(function(){
            var relreset = '.'+$(this).attr('rel');
            if(this.checked == true){       
                $(relreset).fadeIn('fast');
            }else if(this.selected == true){
                $(relset).fadeIn('fast');
            }else{
                $(relreset).fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

From here what we're going to do is give the checkbox, radio, etc, the class="clickme".  This is what makes the function listen for clicks.  On a radio set we need to make sure that each one has the class.

From here we add rel="someuniquename" to the checkbox, radio, etc.  This is going to pass the class of the element we're going to hide. So we'll match it up with the element through the class.

So for example(using coldfusion, hence the #'s)).

Would pass the affect elements with the rel_#minimum_qualifications_id# class.  So our element would look something like this:

Notice that there is a class hideable in there as well.  This hides the element if it's not selected in the beginning.  Otherwise you'd have to wait for a click to hide things.  This will replace any style="display:none"'s.  We have to do it this way otherwise you'll get some display issues.

Comment: And this should work with all radios and checkboxes and selects as long as you have the input have a class of clickme and a rel with a unique name.  Just make sure the rel in the input is assigned as a class in the hidden element.

Comment: Also, don't have a default style of hidden.  That'll mess up the animations.